# Render template wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress

//settings.php

```
<div>
    <p>Settings</p>
    <p><?php echo $text ?></p>
</div>
```

I render template while developing wordpress plugin using require_once

```
  public function display_admin_page() {

        require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'admin/templates/settings.php';
    }
```

When I call the function display_admin_page, I can display the template. However I want to pass some args to template, how can I do it. I want to write a function so I can use like this (but I don't know how to write the function

```
 public function display_plugin_admin_page() {

        $args = [
            'text' => 'Hello' 
        ];

        get_plugin_template('admin/templates/settings.php', $args);
    }
```

Could you guy help me how to write get_plugin_template function? Thanks